# Using SELECT INTO [tableName] in stored procedure not working

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use a table name in a

```
SELECT INTO [tableName]
```

But it complains that [tableName] is expected to be a record variable, row variable, or list of scalar variables. How can I put the result of the select into a table instead of a variable in a stored procedure?

Comment: Are you adding to an existing table? Or trying to create a new one named 'my_table'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an INSERT INTO ... SELECT query, not SELECT INTO. For instance :

```
INSERT INTO my_table (name, my_avg) SELECT name, AVG(col) FROM your_table GROUP BY name
```

Unless you actually wanted to create a new table, where SELECT INTO should work correctly :

```
vsavard_db=> SELECT 1 INTO b;
SELECT
Time : 47,268 ms
vsavard_db=> SELECT * FROM b;
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 line)
```

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the manual here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

you cannot use that syntax inside a pl/pgSQL procedure.

You need to use the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
AS
SELECT ....
```

Comment: What is the reason of answering such questions, when the author is so lazy, that it is easier for him/her to write a question here instead of reading the documentation... do not you fill like spending your time answering them?

Comment: @valgog: I hope(!) that the author is ashamed by finding out how easy it is to find something like this in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, according to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-selectinto.html your stored proc should follow this patter:

```
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT [ ON ( expression [, ...] ) ] ]
* | expression [ AS output_name ] [, ...]
INTO [ TEMPORARY | TEMP ] [ TABLE ] new_table
[ FROM from_item [, ...] ]
[ WHERE condition ]
[ GROUP BY expression [, ...] ]
[ HAVING condition [, ...] ]
[ { UNION | INTERSECT | EXCEPT } [ ALL ] select ]
[ ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC | USING operator ] [, ...] ]
[ LIMIT { count | ALL } ]
[ OFFSET start ]
[ FOR { UPDATE | SHARE } [ OF table_name [, ...] ] [ NOWAIT ] ]
```

EX: SELECT * INTO my_table WHERE x = @myParam

Comment: Putting INTO before or after the column selection leads to the same result. Expected record variable, row variable, or list of scalar variables following INTO.

Comment: It is normally easier to read a documentation about PlPgSQL when writing plPgSQL stored procedure...